# I don't get this recursion

Tags: c, recursion

Given this code:

```
void recursion(int x) {
    if (x > 0) {
         recursion(x-1); 
         printf("%d", x); 
    }  
}
```

Using:

```
recursion(5);
```

Why does it print `12345`? I logically follow the function I would think it would print `43210`

EDIT: sorry if this might look super stupid to you but I'm still learning.

Comment: Because the call to `recursion` is before the `printf`.

Comment: the OP could work this out with pencil and paper...

Comment: @MitchWheat - aww please.. that requires effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow through the steps the code goes through (use a debugger to see it happen in real-time):

```
recursion(5);
if (5 > 0) recursion(4);
if (4 > 0) recursion(3);
if (3 > 0) recursion(2);
if (2 > 0) recursion(1);
if (1 > 0) recursion(0);
if (0 > 0) { // false, so if body skipped and function simply returns}
printf("%d", 1); // The next statement after the call recursion(0)
printf("%d", 2); // The next statement after the call recursion(1)
printf("%d", 3); // The next statement after the call recursion(2)
printf("%d", 4); // The next statement after the call recursion(3)
printf("%d", 5); // The next statement after the call recursion(4)
```

Comment: Now I see why I thought it would print 43210. It doesn't print out immediately after calling recursion(4);

Comment: @walidy Yes, because the recursive function call has to return before the next statement is executed.

Answer (score 2):

When `x = 5`, it calls `recursion(4)`; when `x=4`, it calls `recursion(3)`, etc. When it finally calls `recursion(0)`, the condition is false and the function returns without doing anything. At that point, it returns to the call to `recursion(1)`, where it prints the current value (1) of `x`, then returns to `recursion(2)`, etc.